# Calculate .argmax() across 5000 xarrays

Tags: python, linux, numpy, bigdata, python-xarray

I have around 5000 geotiff files each of (25000,25000) with data value float32.

I wanted to calculate `.argmax()` across 5000 arrays.

So, first tried by merging the data arrays.

`import xarray, rioxarray rasters = [rioxarray.open_rasterio(f) for f in files] merged = xarray.concat(rasters,dim=“band”)`

I m struggled with the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “”, line 42, in
File “/home/laura/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/concat.py”, line 192, in concat
objs, dim, data_vars, coords, compat, positions, fill_value, join, combine_attrs
File “/home/laura/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/concat.py”, line 527, in _dataarray_concat
combine_attrs=“drop”,
File “/home/laura/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/concat.py”, line 384, in _dataset_concat
align(*datasets, join=join, copy=False, exclude=[dim], fill_value=fill_value)
File “/home/laura/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/alignment.py”, line 354, in align
copy=copy, fill_value=fill_value, indexers=valid_indexers
File “/home/laura/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py”, line 2630, in reindex
**indexers_kwargs,
File “/home/laura/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py”, line 2661, in _reindex
sparse=sparse,
File “/home/laura/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/alignment.py”, line 567, in reindex_variables
“index has duplicate values” % dim
ValueError: cannot reindex or align along dimension ‘x’ because the index has duplicate values
```

I tried by putting compat = override or no_conflicts. But, I got same error.

Could someone help me ?

Comment: Can you show the structure of one of the xarray files you opened?

Comment: Do all of these Geotiff files have common coordinates and CRS?

Comment: @horn - For you recent deleted question - "I guess you need to make sure your code is doing video capture at a specific rate., i.e. if you set 10 fps, you should read 10 frames per second to be able to do it properly. To do this, make your code run fast(should be easy) and add delay of `waitKey(1000//fps) - time taken to capture/processing and everything else`. "